# What does "Binds the given function across Right" mean?

Tags: scala

I'm new-ish to functional programming, and I have a question about a description from [the Either documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/Either.html) that I'm having a really hard time wrapping my mind around.

I understand that an `Either` is kind of like an evolution to the `Option` in that an `Either` represents happy and sad path values with `Right` and `Left` similar to how an Option represents the presence or absence of a value with `Some` and `None`. I also understand that an `Option` is a special case of `List`, one containing either 0 or 1 values, which is why we see so many `List`-ish methods (`map`, `filter`, `fold`, etc) on the `Option` type, and by extension, on the `Either` type as well.

I also understand that, at some point, `Either`s were intentionally 'right-biased' so that they could be given given a `flatMap` method, and that this method allows us to transform an `Either[A, B]` into an `Either[C, D]`, which allows us to chain various `Either` computations together and this is the basis for why we're able to use `Either`s in for-comprehensions.

Every time I visit the `Either` documentation, I see that the `flatMap` method has the description "[Binds the given function across Right](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.6/scala/util/Either.html#flatMap%5BA1%3E:A,B1%5D(f:B=%3Escala.util.Either%5BA1,B1%5D):scala.util.Either%5BA1,B1%5D)", and I have never been able to figure out what this description means. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and that this method allows us to transform an `Either[A, B]` into an `Either[C, D]`

This part isn't quite right. While it is true that, if we have `A => C` and `B => D`, then we can convert `Either[A, B]` into `Either[C, D]`, that's not given to us by the "generalization of `Option`" functions you're talking about. When we speak of `Either` as an error-handling type (where, by convention, the error type is the left-hand argument and the "happy path" is the right-hand argument), we generally hold the left-hand argument constant. So the type we're looking at is `Either[A, _]`, where `_` can change but `A` is some *fixed* error type.

Then we get

```
def map[B1](f: (B) => B1): Either[A, B1]
```

That is, our `map` is right-biased. It assumes the left-hand argument (the "sad path") remains the same and only the right-hand argument changes. This isn't a theoretical constraint; we could just as easily have defined `map` to work on the left argument. But we didn't.

Now the word "bind", in particular, comes from Haskell. In particular, it's the usual way to pronounce the [`(>>=)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-) operator defined on the `Monad` typeclass.

> ```
> (>>=) :: m b -> (b -> m b') -> m b'
> ```

I won't get into all of the category-theoretical goodies, except to say that what Haskell calls `(>>=)` (and pronounces "bind") is what Scala calls `flatMap`. On `Either` in Haskell, `(>>=)` looks like this.

```
(>>=) :: Either a b -> (b -> Either a b') -> Either a b'
```

And `flatMap` on Scala's `Either` is defined as<sup>[1]</sup>

```
def flatMap[B1](f: (B) => Either[A, B1]): Either[A, B1]
```

In both cases, we take an `Either[A, B]` and a way to go from `B` to `Either[A, B1]`, and we produce an `Either[A, B1]`. This operation is called "binding" the `Either`. And since we're binding it on the right-hand argument instead of the left-hand one (again, purely a convention, but one we choose and stick to consistently), we say we're binding on the right.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Okay, I lied a little. The full Scala type signature is

> ```
> def flatMap[A1 >: A, B1](f: (B) => Either[A1, B1]): Either[A1, B1]
> ```

This is covering for variance annotations. `A` is covariant in `Either[A, B]`, so strictly speaking we shouldn't be able to have `Either[A, B1]` in argument position for `flatMap`. But we can do this little incantation and have "`Either[A1, B1]` for some `A1 >: A`" as an argument to get basically the same idea.

Comment: Thanks! This was a really good explanation.